# Cassandra hints files not managed properly

Tags: cassandra

I run of the issue of lack of inodes on our machine. It occurred, that most of inodes are taken by Cassandra hints files.

What I already checked is:

- the system table shows there is no hints on any of nodes (0 rows)
- nodetool truncatehints-- in general gives me nothing
- I run repair tool to sync the nodes manually - there was not any improvment
- I want to use some script which will directly remove old hints - like `find /var/lib/cassandra/hints -name *.crc32 -type f -mmin +480`, but I'm not fully convinced if it is safe, especially where the Cassandra itself show nothing about hints.

As far as I understand the process the hints file should be removed automatically whenever the entry is synchronized with proper node.

So, what I can do else to free inodes/remove hints files?

Comment: what version of c* are you on?

Comment: `[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.2.1 | CQL spec 3.4.0 | Native protocol v4]
`

Comment: any chance you can update to 3.11? 3.2 was very buggy

Comment: At some point yes. But, anyway we want to add 2 updated nodes with the data folder on separate partition (with high number of inodes, just in case). For now, we removed hints manually.